# Cheap 120FPS Camera sensor

Tags: video-camera, tracking-devices

I came up with a project for which I'll need a couple of cameras and process their output ideally realtime or with slight delay (feature detection and tracking). Initially I thought about buying couple of cheap web cams, then I realized their framerate and resolution isn't good enough and drivers aren't generally good either. So I went online to look for some sensors and found this website [digikey.com](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/sensors-transducers/image-sensors-camera/532) with a list of hundreds of sensors. But that only found a few items and from only 3 different manufacturers. Also the pricing seems a bit weird. Well ~$10 for 400x400px unit seems like OK, if I didn't have to buy 2500 units in total. On the other hand there are 640x480 sensors for $110. So while I understand buying thousands of units will be always cheaper then buying a single one, I'm a bit confused from this disproportion of prices. I also found different [website](http://photonics.specpick.com/search/cmos-image-sensors/), but that doesn't list prices and manufacturers says, on their websites, to contact their sales dept.

So the actual question is:

- Do you know a sensor that is around 800*600px and
  120FPS or faster + it's price?

I'd expect maybe around $50/unit, but I don't really know how much these things cost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not too rough, if you don't mind ordering from China.  Check out [this ELP-USBFHD01M-L36-120FPS](http://www.ebay.com/itm/1080P-Full-HD-MJPEG-30fps-60fps-120fps-OV2710-CMOS-USB-Camera-Module-Android-/222119769081) on ebay.  It's unbranded, but I've given you the model number so you can find it elsewhere.  Currently, the cheapest place I can find is ebay, but that could change, as per comments.

It actually sports a Full HD CMOS USB Camera, which shoots at 30 / 60 / 120 FPS.  It's going for $45.26 US, plus 99 cents shipping, but it looks like it meets your specifications.

There's also [this ELP-USBFHD01M-L36-120FPS](http://www.ebay.com/itm/2MP-High-Speed-120fps-USB-Camera-Module-3-6mm-OV2710-Color-Sensor-MJPEG-Format-/182222222239) for $49.62, which is actually the same camera from a different ebay seller.

Note that both of these have limited supply, so you may or may not be able to get hold on enough for your project.

Comment: Welcome to Hardware recs! Can you add a bit more details to your answer please? If you remove the links from your answer, it becomes almost useless. We would like the make and model of the cameras as a start. Also, we would like only one device per answer, that way it gives the community to vote/comment on one device at a time.

Comment: @Cfinley, thanks for the clarification!  I'll try to clean it up a bit - and I get what your saying about the links.  Good point.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! That looks very similar to what I wanted. Can't believe I didn't come across those. I'll wait if someone else have something in their sleeves though.

Comment: @anonymous2 Thanks for cleaning this up. Looks good now!